# React-native run-android with no network

Tags: android, react-native

I do not have access to the internet connection all the time but I would like to make a React Native app and run it on the Genymotion Android emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need internet connection to install the React Native CLI and create your app (this will fetch React Native and its JavaScript dependencies).

You'll also need internet connection the first time you run `react-native run-android` because this will download third-party Android dependencies.

Once `run-android` finishes, you should be able to run it again without internet connection (just tried it). Then you should be able to work on your app locally and reload JavaScript, without having an internet connection.

See the [Getting Started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) on the React Native website.

Comment: Is there any way to config the first run to take dependencies from cache, and not from the internet? I copied the cache folder of all the dependencies to the computer without internet

Comment: Is it possible to force offline mode without disabling the network?